# C++: Infinite loop with a simple menu selection

Tags: c++, stdin, infinite-loop

The script I am working on is over a page long, so I am going to link it (one simple file):
http://pastebin.com/7BVHmQGp

I apologize for that. My problem is I get into an infinite loop in my code, for example after I select 1 or 2 for encrypting/unencrypting it lets me enter the word, and when I next enter the "shift" for the cipher it runs an infinite loop of the menu.

I had tried for so many hours to debug this, I thought it was a problem with `cin`, for example when you enter an invalid choice it just throws an infinite loop/

What seems to cause the infininte loops?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use char c; cin.get(c); you'll have to convert it to an integer after

Comment: I was thinking it was std::string too.. It is hard to accept its use if it does this to me each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be ignoring the newline character instead of a space

I tried with the following and it works on VS2010

```
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    getline(cin, input);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried appending that before both of them, and it infinite looped again. :( I even tried before all the `cin`'s. This is so confusing!

Comment: Can you try this '{while ((cin.peek()=='\n')||(cin.peek()=='\r')) cin.get();}'

Comment: Where do I put it, why are there brackets surrounding it, and do you mean cin instead of fin? Thank you.

Comment: instead of cin.ignore use the code 'while ((cin.peek()=='\n')||(cin.peek()=='\r')) cin.get();'

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing as well, the infinite loop spits out both cout/cin requests for entering text+shift + the menu infinite times, its like it somehow completely ignoring each `cin` request infinitely, even though nothing was entered... same thing on someone else's compiler!

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I called this cin.ignore  + cin.clear and it stopped it completely, the problem was mainly with getline() which was accepting a newline unless I used cin.ignore..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try cin.clear, I believe you are constantly reading your initial input character.

```
    cin >> selection;
    cin.clear();
```

Comment: Woah... doing this makes it loop on menu 4 times then awaits my selection.. This did something, heh, I'll try to see what it does, this is so weird why this is happening..

Comment: @Chubsdad is correct it does clear the flags but it seems to stop your loop

Comment: I believe why it is working is that you are reading a char from cin and assigning it to a integer which is causing the error flag to be set, why not change selection to a char and test for char instead of integers.

Comment: Thank you, it worked along with Chubsdad's solution :) I wish I could +1.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/advcpp/iofaq.html) should explain all you need to know.