# c++ validate number and stop infinity loop

Tags: c++, integer

I'm doing a console app, I'm passing an integer to the app and it works ok, but if I pass a letter, it goes crazy,

```
int opt=0;
std::cout<<"Pick lang:"<<'\n';
std::cout<<"1.[es-ES]:"<<'\n';
std::cout<<"2.[en-US]:"<<'\n';
std::cin >> opt;

while(opt<1 || opt>2)
{
    std::cout<<"\nERROR!"<<'\n';
    std::cout<<"Pick lang again:"<<'\n';
    std::cout<<"1.[es-ES]:"<<'\n';
    std::cout<<"2.[en-US]:"<<'\n';
    std::cin >> opt;
}
```

I tried to use isdigit() but I get the same result. Thanks

Comment: When you say "pass a letter", do you mean you're reading a `char`? Or do you mean entering a letter when running the above code?

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342068/c-infinite-loop-with-a-simple-menu-selection/4342247#4342247

Comment: yes, i'm reading a char, but cin is waiting for an int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After performing cin >> extraction, you want to check if the cin stream is still good or not. If you expect cin to extract a number but it gets something else instead, eg. like a letter, then the stream will be set to a bad state and that's why you see it 'going crazy'.

What you have to do is after input, check if cin is still good. If it's in a bad state, you need to clear its flags and then remove out any of the junk data in the stream. If you don't, then subsequent uses of cin will simply fail to function.

Taking your code snippet for example, you can change it to something like this:

```
int opt = 0;
bool inputGood = false;

do
{
    std::cout << "Pick lang again:" << '\n';
    std::cout << "1.[es-ES]:" << '\n';
    std::cout << "2.[en-US]:" << '\n';
    inputGood = std::cin >> opt;
    if(!inputGood)
    {  
      std::cout << "\nERROR! Invalid choice." << '\n';
      cin.clear();
      while( cin.get() != '\n' );
    }
}while(!inputGood || opt < 1 || opt > 2);
```

**Edit:** whoops minor error in the cin error handling. Corrected and should be working now. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the call `std::cin >> opt` is failing to parse the character and returns immediatly (without consuming the buffer), then it finds the same contents and fail....

You should check the result of the operation and react to it. One possibility would be checking the fail bit (`std::cin.fail()`) and failing the whole operation or consuming parts of the buffer (maybe a a single character, maybe more, depending on how you want the application to behave).

The simplest thing would probably be not reading into a number, but rather a character, and then comparing with the expected character:

```
char opt = 0;
do {
   // prompt user for input
   if (! (std::cin >> opt) ) {
      // io error, report and bail out
      break;
   }
} while ( opt != '0' && opt != '1' );
```

Comment: I think you mean `opt != '1' || opt != '2'`. opt can't be both '0' and '1' at the same time, can it ? `:P`

Comment: @Muggen: `opt != '0' || opt != '1'` is equivalent to `true`, since if it is `'0'` it cannot be `'1'` and viceversa (i.e. it is always distinct to '`1`' or distinct to `'0'`). When `opt` is either `'0'` or `'1'` the loop condition has to be `false`... or maybe I am confused?

Comment: @Muggen: you were right in that the condition was wrong. I have changed the loop to a `do-while` instead of a plain `while`. If it had not been for your comment, I would not have realized. Thanks :)

Comment: @David, Actually I run your previous code and it was fine..  What was going on? The `while` needs a `false` to stop. if `opt == '1'` then this means that `opt!='1' && opt!='0'` would be false therefore forcing the loop to exit. counterexample : if `opt == 'z'` then the `while` condition would be `true` and would continue looping.

Comment: In the event of error it would run into an infinite loop (`cin >> opt` would fail, `opt` would not be updated the condition would still hold and the process would be repeated. To test it, send EOF to the application (^D in a linux/macos terminal, I don't remember in windows) and the code would get stuck. The change to a `do-while` is because it seems more natural: execute this at least once and while the condition holds.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a letter this happens:

1. `operator>>` extracts characters from the stream and try to convert them to a number;
2. it fails in the conversion, so it sets the stream state to `ios::failbit` and returns; `opt` probably is untouched (the standard delegates this stuff to the locale library, which is a zone of C++ that I never really understood - for the brave enough, it's at §22.2.2.1.2);
3. since it returned and (probably) `opt` is left as it is, the loop continues;
4. when the execution returns to `std::cin >> opt;`, `operator>>` sees that the state is still `ios::failbit`, so it doesn't even try to extract anything;
5. goto 3.

To fix the problem, you should clean the error state and remove the "wrong" characters from the input buffer. Since you probably don't want to add all that code to every `cin>>`, it's useful to create a function to deal with this common problem; personally, I created this little header (`AcquireInput.hpp`) that has proven useful many times:

```
#ifndef ACQUIREINPUT_HPP_INCLUDED
#define ACQUIREINPUT_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <iosfwd>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

    template<typename InType> void AcquireInput(std::ostream & Os, std::istream & Is, const std::string & Prompt, const std::string & FailString, InType & Result)
    {
        do
        {
            Os<<Prompt.c_str();
            if(Is.fail())
            {
                Is.clear();
                Is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            Is>>Result;
            if(Is.fail())
                Os<<FailString.c_str();
        } while(Is.fail());
    }

    template<typename InType> InType AcquireInput(std::ostream & Os, std::istream & Is, const std::string & Prompt, const std::string & FailString)
    {
        InType temp;
        AcquireInput(Os,Is,Prompt,FailString,temp);
        return temp;
    }

    /* Usage example: 

        //1st overload
        int AnInteger;
        AcquireInput(cout,cin,"Please insert an integer: ","Invalid value.\n",AnInteger);

        //2nd overload (more convenient, in this case)
        int AnInteger=AcquireInput(cout,cin, "Please insert an integer: ","Invalid value.\n");
    */

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

> Reading in numbers directly is
>   problematic
>
> If std::cin is presented with input it
>   cannot process, std::cin goes into a
>   "fail" state The input it cannot
>   process is left on the input stream.
>
> All input will be ignored by std::cin
>   until the "fail" state is cleared:
>   std::cin.clear()
>
> A routine that reads
>   a number directly should:
>
> 1. Read in the
>      number
> 2. Check to see that the input
>      stream is still valid
> 3. If the input
>      stream is not good (!std::cin)
>
>    1. Call
>         std::cin.clear() to take the stream
>         out of the "fail" state.
>    2. Remove from
>         the stream the input that caused the
>         problem: std::cin.ignore(...)
>    3. Get the
>         input again if appropriate or
>         otherwise handle the error

more info here: http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html