# Strange behaviour when reading in int from STDIN

Tags: c++, menu, stdin, infinite-loop

Suppose we have a menu which presents the user with some options:

```
Welcome:
1) Do something
2) Do something else
3) Do something cool
4) Quit
```

The user can press 1 - 4 and then the enter key. The program performs this operation and then presents the menu back to the user. An invalid option should just display the menu again.

I have the following `main()` method:

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
        switch (menu())
        {
            case 1:
                doSomething();
                break;
            case 2:
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
            case 3:
                doSomethingCool();
                break;
            case 4:
                return 0;
            default:
                continue;
        }
}
```

and the follwing `menu()`:

```
int menu()
{
  cout << "Welcome:" << endl
       << "1: Do something" << endl
       << "2: Do something else" << endl
       << "3: Do something cool" << endl
       << "4: Quit" << endl;

  int result = 0;
  scanf("%d", &result);
  return result;
}
```

Entering numerical types works great. Entering 1 - 4 causes the program to perform the desired action, and afterwards the menu is displayed again. Entering a number outside this range such as -1 or 12 will display the menu again as expected.

However, entering something like 'q' will simply cause the menu to display over and over again infinitely, without even stopping to get the user input.

I don't understand how this could possibly be happening. Clearly, `menu()` is being called as the menu is displayed over and over again, however `scanf()` is part of `menu()`, so I don't understand how the program gets into this error state where the user is not prompted for their input.

I originally had `cin >> result` which did exactly the same thing.

**Edit:** There appears to be a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342068/c-infinite-loop-with-a-simple-menu-selection), however the original [source code](http://pastebin.com/7BVHmQGp) has disappeared from pastebin and one of the answers links to an [article](http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/advcpp/iofaq.html) which apparently once explained why this is happening, but is now a dead link. Maybe someone can reply with why this is happening rather than linking? :)

**Edit:** Using [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/), here is how I solved the problem:

```
int getNumericalInput()
{
    string input = "";
    int result;

    while (true)
    {
        getline(cin, input);

        stringstream sStr(input);
        if (sStr >> result)
            return result;

        cout << "Invalid Input. Try again: ";
    }
}
```

and I simply replaced

```
int result = 0;
scanf("%d", &result);
```

with

```
int result = getNumericalInput();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple question about cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864540/a-simple-question-about-cin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you try to convert the non-numeric input to a number, it fails and (the important part) leaves that data in the input buffer, so the next time you try to read an int, it's still there waiting, and fails again -- and again, and again, forever.

There are two basic ways to avoid this. The one I prefer is to read a string of data, then convert from that to a number and take the appropriate action. Typically you'll use `std::getline` to read all the data up to the new-line, and then attempt to convert it. Since it will read whatever data is waiting, you'll never get junk "stuck" in the input.

The alternative is (especially if a conversion fails) to use `std::ignore` to read data from the input up to (typically) the next new-line.

Answer (score 4):

1) Say this to yourself 1000 times, or until you fall asleep:

*I will never ever ever use I/O functions without checking the return value.*

2) Repeat the above 50 times.

3) Re-read your code: Are you checking the result of `scanf`? What happens when `scanf` cannot convert the input into the desired format? How would you go about learning such information if you didn't know it? (Four letters come to mind.)

<sub>I would also question why you'd use `scanf` rather than the more appropriate iostreams operation, but that would suffer from exactly the same problem.</sub>

Comment: I'm accepting Jerry's answer because he actually explained that a failed conversion leaves the user input in the input buffer, causing it to happen over and over again. This not only helps me but everyone else who comes across this question. Plus he explained it without being condescending :)

Comment: @Ozzah: Sure, no worries. Just do be careful with I/O in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify if the read succeeded. Hint: it did not. Always test **after** reading that you successfully read the input:

```
if (std::cin >> result) { ... }
if (scanf("%d", result) == 1) { ... }
```

In C++ the failed state is sticky and stays around until it gets `clear()`ed. As long as the stream is in failed state it won't do anything useful. In either case, you want to `ignore()` the bad character or `fgetc()` it. Note, that failure may be due to having reached the end of the stream in which case `eof()` is set or `EOF` is returned for iostream or stdio, respectively.